# Creating dynamic comboboxes on a dynamic panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create 4 `comboboxes` on a dynamically created `panel` but nothing is showing. What am I missing here, this is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ComboBox[] cmb;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        Panel pnl;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel();
            createCombo();
        }

        private void panel()
        {
            pnl= new Panel();
            pnl.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pnl.Size = new Size(200, 150);

            this.Controls.Add(pnl);
            createCombo();
        }

        private void createCombo()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
            {
                cmb[i] = new ComboBox();
                cmb[i].Text = "CodeCall!";
                cmb[i].Size = new Size(90, 00);
                cmb[i].Location = new Point(i+5, 0);
                pnl.Controls.Add(cmb[i]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Interface shows only the panel:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and the code works fine, provided you're not getting a null reference exception. You need to instantiate your array:

```
private void createCombo()
{
    cmb = new ComboBox[5];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        cmb[i] = new ComboBox();
        cmb[i].Text = "CodeCall!";
        cmb[i].Size = new Size(90, 00);
        cmb[i].Location = new Point(i+5, 0);
        pnl.Controls.Add(cmb[i]);
     }
}
```

For me, the combobox appeared without issue. However they all appear almost on top of eachother, you'll need to set cmb[i].Location differently.  Also, I personally would recommend this instead of what you are doing:

```
private void createCombo()
{
    cmb = new ComboBox[5];
    int width = 90;
    int height = 25;
    int spacing = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        ComboBox newBox = new ComboBox();
        newBox.Text = "CodeCall!";
        newBox.Size = new Size(width, height);
        newBox.Location = new Point((i*width)+spacing, 0);
        cmb[i] = newBox;
        pnl.Controls.Add(newBox);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I initially thought the problem was the height:

```
cmb[i].Size = new Size(90, 00);
```

However, it turns out you actually *cannot* set the height for a ComboBox.

---

The *real* problem is a `NullReferenceException` that is getting swallowed (you must be on a 64-bit system). You never initialize `cmb` and thus it is null when `cmb[i] = new ComboBox()` is called.

See http://blog.adamjcooper.com/2011/05/why-is-my-exception-being-swallowed-in.html for an explanation as to why this happens but the conditions that must be met are (quoting):

> 1. You are running on a 64-bit version of Windows (whether your application is built for 32-bit or 64-bit doesn’t matter; only the bit depth of the OS)
> 2. You are building a WinForms app
> 3. You are debugging the application with Visual Studio (using default options for Exception catching)
> 4. Your main form has a Load event handler
> 5. During the execution of your Load handler, an exception occurs

Comment: Interestingly, when I set the height, it never overrides the default value of 25. Setting it to 0 appears to have no effect. Which makes me wonder, how DO you set the height?

Comment: @MikeC. That is interesting, apparently you cannot set the height for a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the height:
>
> cmb[i].Size = new Size(90, 00);

Answer doesn't include exact answer.
The problem is that you have a 0 for height. Try for example:

```
cmb[i].Size = new Size(90, 90);
```